# <logic:equal> is not working

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans

I m trying to do something like this--

```
<logic:equal name='<%=session.getAttribute(Att.INFO)%>' value='<%=Att.INF%>'  scope='session'><h3>Equal</h3></logic:equal>
```

but it is showing nothing.

Comment: where is your property attribute of the tag?

Comment: property attribute is not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

add your property dude. 
Example :

```
<logic:equal name="SomeThing" property="LENGTH_OF_MY_ATT" value="20">
<p>your length is 20</p>
</logic:equal>
```